# Parsing jQuery JSON data in PHP

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting JSON data through an API using jQuery.  Now I am unable to get the JSON data in my PHP code

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=?",
  function(json) {
      document.write("Geolocation information for IP address : ", json.ip);
      document.write("Country  : ", json.country);
      document.write("Latitude : ", json.latitude);
      document.write("Longitude : ", json.longitude);
  }
 );
});
</script>

//result is below on browser
//Geolocation information for IP address : 45.114.126.32Country : PakistanLatitude : 30Longitude : 70
```

Now I want to get the latitude and longitude values in my PHP code.  How can I parse this code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you send the json data via ajax:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=?",
        function(json) {

            $.ajax({
                   type: 'post',
                   url: 'action_receive_json.php';
                   data : json
                   });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Then you can manipulate back the JSON data in PHP code (in this case `action_receive_json.php` file):

```
$country = $_POST['country'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

//....
```

Comment: Oh..Php code?  Create a php file anywhere you please... :) as long as the url same as in ajax.